# UIDynamics dragging unresponsive after clicking Menu button

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

I'm trying to implement UI dynamics from the example at https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController on my project and my screen gets unresponsive after pressing my Menu button which runs the following code:

```
[self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:YES];
```

Any ideas what I'm probably doing wrong?

NOTE: If I don't press Menu button I can show / hide the sidebar every time I want by dragging the top screen.

NOTE 2: If you know about a better sliding view library, I'm all ears :-)

Comment: Isn't this question best directed at the developer of ECSlidingViewController?

Comment: In his Readme.md [link]https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/blob/master/README.md says _"If you need help using ECSlidingViewController, please post a question on StackOverflow with the "ECSlidingViewController" tag."_

Just to be sure, I did both. But I feel like I'm going to switch to another library this is way too complex and has little support.